# Splitting array of images and arranging them on a UIView

Tags: arrays, swift, uiview

I am trying to dynamically arrange set of image data in an array on a `UIView`I want four per role and max role is 12 making 4 per role. This is the problem, I can I split the array and place the images evenly where each and everyone should be. Eg:

12 Images

```
  ======|=====|======|======|
        |     |      |      |
        |     |      |      |
  ======|=====|======|======|
        |     |      |      |
        |     |      |      |
  ======|=====|======|======|
        |     |      |      |
        |     |      |      |
  |=====|=====|======|======|
```

I know how to arrange the image, but then splitting the array is the problem. What if I have 7 images in the array that would be 4 at the top, 3 at the bottom or 10, which would be 4,4,2. I don't know how to go about it. That's why I don't have any code pasted at all. Any help on splitting and arranging the array would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you want a `UICollectionView`. There are many tutorials for it on the web.

Comment: I am already using a UICollectionView in the view this is needed. So, there are four different views which I switch with Tab Icons. But, then a view belonging to a tab has a collectionview with header. So, I was like why use a `UICollectionView` inside another. Why not just draw it away

Comment: Please look at my comment below

Answer (score 1):

Storing values in a single array and using the array as a data source for a 2D structure is fairly common. You can get the X and Y positions based on the index of the item and the width and height of the structure.

```
// number of images across the view
let width = 4;

// number of images down the view
let height = 3;

// index of the image in the array
let index = 10;

// index of the space from the left
// starting with 0
let xLocation = index % width; // 2

// index of the space from the top
// starting with 0
let yLocation = index / width; // 2
```

A function that returns the values as a tuple is below. All that you'd need to do is iterate over your array and it will return the positions of the items based on the provided information.

```
func getPosition(width:Int, index:Int) -> (Int,Int) {
  return (index % width, index / width);
}
```

edit: code clarification

Comment: Please look at my comment below

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what I did. I wrote a function that extends Array to split my Array evenly

```
 extension Array {
func splitBy(subSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
    return 0.stride(to: self.count, by: subSize).map { startIndex in
        let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(subSize, limit: self.count)
        return Array(self[startIndex ..< endIndex])
    }
}
}
```

Then, I did the bit of displaying the images with this

```
 private func setGridView(gridCell: ProfileGrid, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {//140813008
    let (location, photoCount, images) = dummyGrid[indexPath.row]
    gridCell.imageCount.text = photoCount
    gridCell.location.text = location
    if images.count > 0 && images.count <= 4 {
        for index in 0..<images.count {
            let dedicatedWidth = self.view.frame.size.width/4 - 8
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (dedicatedWidth + 2) * CGFloat(index), y: 0, width: CGFloat(dedicatedWidth - 2), height: 80))
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: images[index])
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            gridCell.imageHolder.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    } else if images.count > 4 && images.count <= 8 {
        let split = images.splitBy(4)
        let firstSplit = split[0]
        let secondSplit = split[1]

        for index in 0..<firstSplit.count {
            let dedicatedWidth = self.view.frame.size.width/4 - 8
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (dedicatedWidth + 2) * CGFloat(index), y: 0, width: CGFloat(dedicatedWidth - 2), height: 80))
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: firstSplit[index])
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            gridCell.imageHolder.addSubview(imageView)
        }

        for jDex in 0..<secondSplit.count {
            let dedicatedWidth = self.view.frame.size.width/4 - 8
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (dedicatedWidth + 2) * CGFloat(jDex), y: 82, width: CGFloat(dedicatedWidth - 2), height: 80))
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: secondSplit[jDex])
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            gridCell.imageHolder.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    } else if images.count > 8 {
        let split = images.splitBy(4)
        let firstSplit = split[0]
        let secondSplit = split[1]
        let thirdSplit = split[2]

        for index in 0..<firstSplit.count {
            let dedicatedWidth = self.view.frame.size.width/4 - 8
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (dedicatedWidth + 2) * CGFloat(index), y: 0, width: CGFloat(dedicatedWidth - 2), height: 80))
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: firstSplit[index])
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            gridCell.imageHolder.addSubview(imageView)
        }

        for jDex in 0..<secondSplit.count {
            let dedicatedWidth = self.view.frame.size.width/4 - 8
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (dedicatedWidth + 2) * CGFloat(jDex), y: 82, width: CGFloat(dedicatedWidth - 2), height: 80))
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: secondSplit[jDex])
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            gridCell.imageHolder.addSubview(imageView)
        }

        for tDex in 0..<thirdSplit.count {
            let dedicatedWidth = self.view.frame.size.width/4 - 8
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (dedicatedWidth + 2) * CGFloat(tDex), y: 164, width: CGFloat(dedicatedWidth - 2), height: 80))
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: thirdSplit[tDex])
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            gridCell.imageHolder.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The Achievement]

If you've a better of doing it, I don't mind. My code is too big and kinda not professional from my on look of it. Ideas please